# Emphasis (it is ... that) with comparison (less, more...)

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison, emphasis

I'm not sure how to use "less" and/or "more" in an "emphasizing sentence" (if it's the term).

> *It is* less the quality of the alcohol, *but more* the quantity, *that* leads to the problem.

or

> *It is* less the quality *than* the quantity of the alcohol *that* leads to the problem.

Thank you all :)

Comment: "It is less the quality of the alcohol, **and** more the quantity, that leads to the problem" is natural. The other sentence is also natural exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Glad to learn that! Thank you, dear gotube :)